# Form_form vs Simple_form (Collections: value_method, label_method)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, form-for, ruby-on-rails-5.2

In simple_form, you can do use label_method and value_method, like the below..

```
f.association :company, collection: Company.all.order(:name), label_method: :name, value_method: :value
```

1) Does form_for have the same methods?

2) What are the default values for :label_method and :value_method in SimpleForm?

#### Solution (set in initializer):

```
config.collection_label_methods = [ :to_label, :name, :title, :to_s ]
config.collection_value_methods = [ :id, :to_s ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, default FormBuilder has same abilities:

```
<%= form_for @yourmodel do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :company_id, Company.all.order(:name), :id, :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

According to `collection_select helper` [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/collection_select)

> **collection_select**(method, collection, value_method, text_method,
>   options = {}, html_options = {}) public

```
# File actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb, line 834
def collection_select(method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
    @template.collection_select(@object_name, method, collection, value_method, text_method, objectify_options(options), @default_html_options.merge(html_options))
end
```